# Google chrome is starting automatically --headless --disable-gpu --remote -debuging-port=9222 URL, making my computer slow

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, headless

For many days I saw a weird behavior of google chrome that it automatically starts some program in the background and that utilizes more than 70% of my CPU, and some integrated GPU as well. I change the access of chrome by default as administrator and I found that after every system restarts its starting google chrome with given below screenshot:

[Google chrome opening screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6IXj.jpg)

I found that it tries to run chrome with some arguments "chrome --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 and calling one URL.

This behavior is quite weird, and I found that it's a utility by google in web development activity or similar like that, but why enforcing other users and make the computer slow.

Is there any way to disable this permanently rather than clicking on NO every time at windows startup? Any help or suggestion will be really helpful.